# behavior of iterators in nested loops versus random access in C++

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Why do the following code snippets give different outputs?  (see outputs below)

Snippet 1:

```
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);
vector<int>::const_iterator iterv1=v.begin();
vector<int>::const_iterator iterv2=v.begin();
for(;iterv1!=v.end();++iterv1){
    for(;iterv2!=v.end();++iterv2){
        cout << "*iterv1 = " << *iterv1 << " *iterv2 = " << *iterv2 << endl;
    }
}
```

Ouptut:

```
*iterv1 = 1 *iterv2 = 1
*iterv1 = 1 *iterv2 = 2
```

Code snippet 2:

```
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);
for(int i=0;i<2;++i){
    for(int j=0;j<2;++j){
        cout << "v[i] = " << v[i] << " v[j] = " << v[j] << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
v[i] = 1 v[j] = 1
v[i] = 1 v[j] = 2
v[i] = 2 v[j] = 1
v[i] = 2 v[j] = 2
```

I would have expected the same (numerical output.  Clearly there is something I am not understanding about iterators.  Can someone help?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you don't reset `iterv2` to the beginning in the inner loop. You should place the initialization code where it belongs: in the for-initialization.

Either just move the assignment in the for-initialization:

```
vector<int>::const_iterator iterv1;
vector<int>::const_iterator iterv2;
for(iterv1=v.begin();iterv1!=v.end();++iterv1){
    for(iterv2=v.begin();iterv2!=v.end();++iterv2){
        cout << "*iterv1 = " << *iterv1 << " *iterv2 = " << *iterv2 << endl;
    }
}
```

Or even put the variables inside of the loop if they aren't needed afterwards:

```
for(vector<int>::const_iterator iterv1=v.begin();iterv1!=v.end();++iterv1){
    for(vector<int>::const_iterator iterv2=v.begin();iterv2!=v.end();++iterv2){
        cout << "*iterv1 = " << *iterv1 << " *iterv2 = " << *iterv2 << endl;
    }
}
```

By the way, if you use C++11, you can make use of the two following new language-features: The `auto` keyword can be used to leave out the type specification (not to be confused with dynamic typing, as this still is static typing, meaning that the compiler figures out the type and compiles it the same way as you wrote the type explicitly):

```
for(auto iterv1=v.begin();iterv1!=v.end();++iterv1){
    for(auto iterv2=v.begin();iterv2!=v.end();++iterv2){
        cout << "*iterv1 = " << *iterv1 << " *iterv2 = " << *iterv2 << endl;
    }
}
```

And the new syntax for range-based for-loop (similar to Java's) will make it a lot easier to both write and (far more important) to read:

```
for(auto iterv1 : v){
    for(auto iterv2 : v){
        cout << "*iterv1 = " << *iterv1 << " *iterv2 = " << *iterv2 << endl;
    }
}
```

P.S. The same error would have happened if you moved the initializations outside of the loops in your index-based version:

```
// WRONG - SAME ERROR
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
for(;i<2;++i){
    for(;j<2;++j){
        cout << "v[i] = " << v[i] << " v[j] = " << v[j] << endl;
    }
}
```

PP.S. Add spaces around operators to make your code slightly more readable. Most code style guidelines require that.

Comment: Re your PPS: It depends somewhat on culture.  I learned programming in France, and I tend to use a lot of spaces---normal French typography also uses more space than most.  (I.e. a space before ;, :, ! or ?.)  When I worked in Germany, the convention was practically no space except when necessary; the normal German typography uses very little white space, often even omitting it between words.  People are conditioned by what they are used to.

Comment: @JamesKanze I'm German and there is a difference if you leave out the space between two words, it is then really one word. I think it's an international typographical rule to put a white space after (, . ! ? : ; etc.) The space in front of and after binary operators (+ - * / etc.) is smaller than the white space in text. But I'd strongly recommend to put some spaces around them. Of course, this is just a recommendation, but most code style guidelines I know (e.g. Google) require them.

Comment: For a circular definition of word (i.e. a word is what is set off by white space).  For most "logical" definitions, "qu'est-ce" is one word in French (although it looks like three), and "Schadenfreude" is two words (although it looks like one).  And the French put space _before_ larger punctuation, and not just after, e.g. "C'est quoi ?", and not "C'est quoi?".  (Some, like ";", get a narrower space in non fixed width fonts.)  Overall, compared to English, there will be less spaces in German, and more in French.  And coding guidelines often reflect this.

Comment: And of course, the Google coding guidelines are almost certainly based on English use, not German or French.  (Most French programmers I've worked with will put a space before the semicolon, for example.  And the usual pattern when I worked at the Dresdner Bank in Frankfurt was something like "`if(x==y)`...".  But a lot of projects I worked on in Germany were international, and adopted English conventions.)

Comment: "Schadenfreude" is one word. One nice "feature" of the German language is that you can build new words by concatenation (and maybe slight adaptations). But some concatenated words have a meaning on their own, so it's the case with "Schadenfreude" [For non-Germans: "Schaden" = damage, "freunde" = joy, "Schadenfreude" = spitefullness]. It doesn't mean (in general) to be happy about *any* damage. And still, if you concatenate words to build a new one, you count it as one word.

Comment: According to one (somewhat circular) definition of word.  Most linguists wouldn't consider it a single word, and even if this one would be (in the sense that it has a meaning beyond the simple concatenation), other cases wouldn't be: as you say, you can "create" arbitrary compounds in German, but they'd be separate words in any other language.  (English does the same thing, but it leaves the spaces in.  French is more complex, but you get whole phrases, such as "qu'en-dirait-on" which act as a single word.  Even though they are written as many words.)

Comment: To come back to the topic: I suggest to code in an international style. I never write variable names or (non-documentation) comments in my local language (German) but always in English. It's easier to read (because of the programming language's keywords in between) as well as better for community-driven or international projects. As code style guidelines are supposed for whole teams and not just single persons, they shouldn't make assumptions on the team member's nationality / culture. Just my opinion. :)

Comment: I tend to agree, but there is at least one argument for the opposite: there's less chance of a keyword conflict.  When I moved from C to C++, I was hit by some members named `class`.  Obviously, this wouldn't have occured if they'd been named `classe` (French) or `Klasse` (German):-).  (I've also seen a program written in Japanese.  The keywords really stick out when everything else is in Kanji.  On the other hand, it was very hard for me to keep track of names when I didn't have the slightest idea of how to pronounce them, much less what they meant.)